# how to change color of series on angular google chart directive

Tags: angularjs, google-visualization

I have columns:

```
chart.data = {
  'cols': [
    {id: 'date', label: 'Generation Date', type: 'date', p: {}},
    {id: 'successCount', label: 'Success Count', type: 'number', p: {}},
    {id: 'failureCount', label: 'Failure Count', type: 'number', p: {}}
  ]
};


chart.options = {
  series: {
    0: {color: '#e2431e'},
    1: {color: '#e7711b'}
  }
};
```

Colors are not showing up on my line chart. Any idea how to set the color for `successCount` and `failureCount` series?

Answer (score 0):

you could try using the `colors` [configuration option](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/gallery/columnchart#configuration-options)

```
chart.options = {
  colors: ['#e2431e', '#e7711b']
};
```

Comment: It worked after I added this to options:         forceIFrame: true,